# Блоки одинаковой высоты

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Если заполняется один из блоков, то оба блока принимают наибольшую высоту.
Вариант с фиксированной высотой не подойдет.
будет ли правильно сделать блокам display:table или всё же есть более правильный способ?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот Вариант с `flexbox`։

```css
.list
    {
        width: 400px;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;

        -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .list__item
    {
        width: 40%;
        background: #3e3e3b;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        padding: 2%;
        margin: 0 3%;
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }
```

```html
<ul class="list">
    <li class="list__item">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</li>
    <li class="list__item">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</li>
    <!-- остальные элементы -->
</ul>
```

Comment: Ширина обязательно должна быть фиксированной или можно в процентах?

Comment: @StepanIvanov с шириной можно манипулировать как угодно.